# Accessing command line arguments beyond the 9th in bash script

Tags: bash, parameter-passing

I am trying to read command line arguments in bash but I have problems to read on the 10th column.
Here is my sample script:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------
#!/bin/bash
an=$2  mn=$4  dy=$6  der=$8  new=$10  sec=(${12} ${13})
echo $an $mn  $dy   $der  $new  $sec 
#--------------------------------------------------------
```

I have run the above script "test.sh" as

```
./test.sh -yr cat  -mn Jan  -dy  tuesday  -der tt  -new car -sec 001 001
```

The output is:

```
cat Jan tuesday tt -yr0 001
```

But for variable $new ($10) the answer should have been `car`  but I get `-yr0`

Any idea why?

Comment: You should probably consider using getopt(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fix:

```
#!/bin/bash
an=$2  mn=$4  dy=$6  der=$8  new=${10}  sec="${12} ${13}"
echo $an $mn  $dy   $der  $new  $sec
```

1. Instead of $10, which is "$1" with 0 appended, use ${10}
2. sec="..." instead of using parentheses, unless you meant to use array

Answer (score 4):

`new=$10` is giving you `$1` (i.e 'yr') appended with `0`. You need some braces : `${10}`