# How to Pass More then 10 argument in ShellScript

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
 sed  -e "s/${MyToken}/${arg}/g" file
```

Value Of 'arg' working fine till 9th argument.after 10th arguments its failing

Comment: What is the value of the 9th and 10th arguments?

Comment: write the full code and error because this works for me. shell script excepts up to 255 arguments and with ${} it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line arguments in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935444/command-line-arguments-in-bash-script)

Comment: The syntax `${10}` is fine. Example: `set $(seq 10); echo ${10}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
#!/bin/ksh   
echo There is $# parameters
while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
         echo $1
         shift
    done
```

The output :

```
     Will:/home> ./script a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
     There is 26 parameters
        a
        b
        c
        d
        e
        f
        g
        h
        i
        j
        k
        l
        m
        n
        o
        p
        q
        r
        s
        t
        u
        v
        w
        x
        y
        z
```

`$#`count the number of parameters passed to your script.

`Shift` is moving the param to the left so after one loop `$1` become b and so on.